# How to deploy a php website in IIS 5.0?

Tags: php, iis, iis-5

Do I need to install anything for the IIS to support PHP?
And how can I deploy a php website using the IIS 5.0?

Comment: http://php.iis.net/     0.1 seconds of googling for "php iis"

Comment: Have you actually even tried the windows installer of PHP? http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: @MarcB, php on iis7 and not iis5

Comment: @hackre, where's the iis on that? oO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install the PHP interpreter as an IIS ISAPI extension service. I don't know if the most recent version of PHP is still available for such an old version of IIS but basically you need to obtain a PHP installation package design to be deployed on Windows, as an ISAPI extension .dll.

Have a look at the PHP Manual's [section on installing on Windows with IIS 5.0 and/or IIS 6.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php).